# Trying to delete before a given node

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the two functions below and I can get the removeAfter function to work correctly but then when trying to implement the removeBefore function the linked list is not changed at all. Am I missing something? I have made necessary changes, but am still getting the same result: removeBefore does not output any changes to the list.

```
    // remove the node after the node p
void DoublyLinkedList::removeAfter(DListNode &p){
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw EmptyDLinkedListException("Empty Doubly Linked List");
    }

    DListNode *to_delete = &p;
    to_delete = to_delete->next;

    if (to_delete != NULL){
        if(to_delete->next != NULL){
            to_delete->prev->next = to_delete->next;
        }

        if(to_delete->prev != NULL){
            to_delete->next->prev = &p;
        }
        if (to_delete == &trailer) {
            trailer = *to_delete->prev;
        }


    }
    if (to_delete == NULL){
        throw EmptyDLinkedListException("Cannot delete a null pointer");
    }
    delete to_delete;
}

// remove the node before the node p
void DoublyLinkedList::removeBefore(DListNode &p){
        /* Complete this function */
    if (isEmpty()){
        throw EmptyDLinkedListException("Empty Doubly Linked List");
    }

    DListNode *to_delete = &p;
    to_delete = to_delete->prev;

    if (to_delete != NULL){
        if (to_delete->next != NULL) {
            to_delete->next->prev = to_delete->prev;
        }
        if (to_delete->prev != NULL) {
            to_delete->prev->next = to_delete->next;
        }

        if (to_delete == &header) {
             header = *to_delete->next;
        }

    }

    if (to_delete == NULL){
        throw EmptyDLinkedListException("Cannot delete a null pointer");
    }

    delete to_delete;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are errors in your code.

First off, a linked list is a list of pointers, so it is not customary to pass around nodes by reference. You really should be passing them by pointer instead.

`removeAfter()` does not account for the possibility that `p.next` might be NULL upon input (when `p` is the last node in the list).  And it is not updating `to_delete`'s siblings correctly before then deleting `to_delete` itself.  It should look like this instead:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::removeAfter(DListNode *p)
{
    DListNode *to_delete = p->next; //Get to the node after p that is to be deleted
    if (to_delete != NULL)
    {
        if (to_delete->next != NULL) {
            to_delete->next->prev = to_delete->prev;
        }

        if (to_delete->prev != NULL) {
            to_delete->prev->next = to_delete->next;
        }


        // update the tail pointer if to_delete is the tail node...
        if (trailer == to_delete) {
            trailer = to_delete->prev;
        }

        delete to_delete;
    }
}
```

`removeBefore()` is making similar mistakes.  It does not account for the possibility that `p.prev` might be NULL upon input (when `p` is the first node in the list) or even that it might be the head node of the list.  It should look like this instead:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::removeBefore(DListNode *p)
{
    DListNode *to_delete = p->prev; //Get to the node before p that is to be deleted

    if (to_delete != NULL)
    {
        if (to_delete->next != NULL) {
            to_delete->next->prev = to_delete->prev;
        }

        if (to_delete->prev != NULL) {
            to_delete->prev->next = to_delete->next;

        // update the head pointer if to_delete is the head node...

        if (header == to_delete) {
            header = to_delete->next;
        }

        delete to_delete;
    }
}
```

That being said, the logic would be better implemented by centralizing it, eg:

```
void DoublyLinkedList::remove(DListNode *p)
{
    if (p = NULL) return;

    if (p->next != NULL) {
        p->next->prev = p->prev;
    }

    if (p->prev != NULL) {
        p->prev->next = p->next;
    }

    if (header == p) {
        header = p->next;
    }


    if (trailer == p) {
        trailer = p->prev;
    }

    delete p;
}

void DoublyLinkedList::removeAfter(DListNode *p)
{
    remove(p->next);
}

void DoublyLinkedList::removeBefore(DListNode *p)
{
    remove(p->prev);
}
```

That being said, once you understand how double-linked lists work, you should throw away all of this code and just use the STL [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) class instead, which is a standard double-linked list implementation.